# Why isn't phase modulation commonly used in radio stations?

Tags: amplitude-modulation

I've tried searching about this and see answers saying that "frequency modulation can be considered as phase modulation" and I do understand that frequency and phase affect each other but why don't stations use direct phase modulation? As in the stations are actually called PM and phase is the variable directly being modulated. Probably there are ways that phase modulation is integrated but I'm kind of looking for a straight up answer that someone not into electronics who is curious why FM and AM stations are the only common radio stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are constant carrier angle modulation schemes with exponential side bands that must be attenuated to fit in the required BW to prevent adjacent channel interference in expected capture range of signals.

Variables include: the ratio FM modulation index which has a log proportional SNR improvement factor for \$\dfrac{\Delta f_c}{f_{in}}\$ for a carrier fc to noise ratio (CNR) above 10dB which requires a squelch below to block the abrupt change in noise. It also requires some pre-emphasis to maintain that SNR improvement somewhat like what vinyl music recordings had. This is because FM is the integral of PM so the deviation ratio improvement is needed more for high input frequencies but not simply differentiated over 3 decades but with plateaus.

Using PM for audio would challenge the dynamic range of the receiver demodulator as the carrier low frequency FM noise then would be approached by low frequency audio.

**So the PM is better suited for data where the frequency span is more limited by design , so you would never see. A thousand zeros and ones followed by 010101.**, yet in audio the SNR of bass must be perceived as good as treble.

The metric for compressing BW in PM results in a higher ratio  of Bits per Baud at the expense of threshold for SNR in PM for data is determine by the number of quantum phases out of 360 deg.  For GOES uplinks, 8-PSK is now common and is QPSK. But when GOES 1 was first launched.

### anecdotal

I recall in ‘78, GOES uplink was a low bit binary bit rate of 150 bps in a 750 Hz channel on a 420 MHz or so carrier with a 10W amplifier. The frequency error was very critical at power on during preamble and even tighter on the start of data. My mentor Bill Whitehead, designed the UHF Tx and he asked me to measure the phase modulation in degrees to very tight specs using a fancy HP “Time Interval counter” on the carrier to measure phase change on the UHF carrier. I had a HP9825    HP basic computer at the time, so it took me one afternoon to make a program to measure these and test more specifications and printout with the tiny strip printer. 90 degrees (?) at 420 MHz is a really small shift, yet this rack mount handled it with ease at the low bit rate. The internal clock was ultra-stable but used a quartz PLL to reduce the phase noise.

**The benefit of PM here is controlled suppression of side-bands with an equal-weighting of SNR on input frequencies over a narrow 8 bit range.**

Answer (score 2):

There is actually little difference between FM and PM.  The reason is that when you change the frequency you necessarily change the phase to get there.  Likewise, when you change the phase you end up changing the frequency to get there.

Some FM schemes actually use PM and simply adjust the input signal to compensate for the slight difference so that the output ends up being exactly the same.

Why don't we use PM vs. FM?  Well for the commercial FM broadcast band, FM was chosen long ago.  If someone started broadcasting PM modulated music, it would sound funny on radios all over the place because they are expected FM, not PM.

Can PM be used for broadcast?  Yes it can and there is no reason why a band could not be created that used it.  But currently there is not such a band.  PM is often used by Radio Amateurs (HAMs) along with just about all other forms of modulation.  PM is used in your WiFi router, your mobile phone, and DBS satellite TV systems.

Comment: The key difference is that when you decode a PM signal with an FM receiver (or vice-versa), you get a non-flat frequency response.

Comment: Specifically, frequency is just the rate of change of phase, so an integrator or differentiator in the baseband before the modulator allows you to convert one into the other. The early crystal controlled FM transmitters (Pre PLL) used a thing called an Armstrong modulator, which was really a phase modulator that was then multiplied up to get to the required 75kHz deviation.